# Selenium script for click the search box in office 365 webmail

Tags: selenium-webdriver

when clicking the search field in office 365 webmail the xpath is

```
.//*@id='primaryContainer']/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button
```

but selenium identifies for the first time and not for the second time.

is there any way to write selenium script using

```
<span class="_n_t ms-font-weight-semilight ms-font-color-neutralPrimary">Search Mail and People</span>
```

or any way to identify?

Answer (score 0):

You can try finding it by the text it has.

`//span[text() = 'Search Mail and People']`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `CSS Selector` with `@FindBy` annotation instead of `XPATH` like:

```
@FindBy(css="[class='login_textfield textfield required email field normaltext']")
WebElement emailField;
```

Sorry, I'm not registered, so I cannot provide you deeper example, hope it helps you enough :)

See at:
http://screencast.com/t/rqa9dOoy9iq

**Edit**: 
I saw that you uploaded some source, try:

```
@FindBy(css="[class='_n_t ms-font-weight-semilight ms-font-color-neutralPrimary']")
WebElement someWebElementVariable;
```

Comment: How do you know the asker is using `Java`? `@FinyBy` is not available in all languages.

Comment: @RemcoW well if OP doesn't specify a language, then they get what they get. It's not Gergo's fault. He's just trying to help.

Comment: @JeffC I'm not saying it is. But if you're gonna give a language specific answer least you can do is mention it.

Comment: Sorry, when I saw the "selenium" word, only the java solution was in my mind, but you are right. However the CSS selector specification is corrent, this can help the asker when defining the WebElement. Sorry for the confiuon.

Comment: I see that you are working on a Wolters Kluwer project, I guess you are using Js+selenium.